# Como validar que un select de una columna venga con un dato especifico y controlar sus datos si viene null

Tags: sql-server

Buen día tengo un problema básico pero que la verdad no e podido concluir tengo en claro que si quiero traer una columna de un dato especifico es:

```
SELECT columna = 'Valor' FROM Tabla;
```

y para darle un valor si viene null es:

```
SELECT isnull(Valor,'nuevoValorSiesNull') FROM Tabla;
```

Pero no tengo muy claro como puedo combinarlo ya lo e intentado haciéndolo de distintas maneras y sigue estando erróneo, ¿como podría realizar la consulta?

Muchas gracias de antemano.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Comprendo que queres obtener un campo y si este campo está vacío, mostrar un valor por defecto.

Entonces de ser así; prueba con esto

```
select isnull(columna,'defecto') from tabla
```

Te traerá ese campo en especifico y si no hay dato para x fila, le pondrá (para este caso) 'defecto'

Si lo que queres es traer un campo de la tabla con un valor en especifico, no funciona el que utilices la sentencia "isnull", ya que la consulta sería algo así:

```
select columna from tabla where columna='valor'
```

Ahí el resulta será solo aquellos campos de la columna que contengan el "valor" de búsqueda.

Comment: muchas gracias, si funciona!

Comment: Magnífico Un gusto.